# Do Playstation 2's still work while offline using only games disks?

Tags: ps2

I'm wondering if Playstation 2's still work to play with games disks while offline.

Comment: I dont think the PS2 even had real online capabilities. As far as I know you needed to buy some extra modems and whatnot to even get it online. Apart from that I dont know why you dont just plug the ps2 in and start it up? That would immediately answer your question. Especially because you cannot even plug in a LAN cable or such. Not being able to play (some) games due to closed servers is something that just recently have come up in online only games.

Comment: Absolutely, why wouldn't it ?

Comment: He asked if they worked for *offline* games not online.

Comment: Generally speaking, the PS2 will still work, as others have already noted. If you're asking about a specific PS2 unit, there's no way we can tell without inspecting the device itself.

Answer (score 2):

The Playstation 2 with networking capabilities was shown off at E3 2001, with a collection of peripherals that would enable free multiplayer over a broadband connection (in the US, other regions were provided different adapters). However, the console still had plenty of titles that could be enjoyed fully in a single player or local co-op fashion.

I cannot find information on **online only** titles on the PS2, because that would answer your question properly. However, [there is a list of games on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PlayStation_2_online_games) that includes all online multiplayer titles for the PS2. The list is far too long to convert to an answer here, however the list is not overly important to this answer.

To fully answer your question, yes, your PS2 will still work with game disks only, long after the collapse of society and our global Internet infrastructure, just as long as the laser reader holds up.

Comment: And the electrical supply chain is not destroyed!

Answer (score 0):

I have a ps2 with game discs and they work just fine for offline games, I haven't tried online.  Game discs really cant be discontinued, the only thing that can happen is the online capabilities can be removed because the servers get shut down, but the offline functionality should remain as long as your hardware lasts.

My only problem is that a lot of the discs wont read because either my laser is ruined or my ps2 needs a blowout, but that's my hardware problem and yours quite likely wont have it.  Happy Gaming!